# How to make token based authentication login in codeigniter 3

Tags: authentication, access-token, codeigniter-3, restful-architecture

I am working with an API project build in codeigniter which have login and register methods, now I have to implement the token based login. Please suggest how can I do the same. I am using https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver for basic API configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Use Microtime function of php and then md5 it. you will get unique token for every user login.

Comment: and use this generated token for user activities.